# Links don't work when combining SVG files with hovers

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, opacity

I am trying to achieve the following

- Text and svg files move when hovering
- Color is reversed when hovering.
- Open the link

This is my html:
`btn_ol`class has `<a>` and `<span>`(with object svg)

```
<div class="btn_ol">
    <a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank"></a>
    <span>Google<object class=ol_svg data="../assets/images/common/icon_ol.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></span>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
.btn_ol {
    padding: 2.3rem 1.8rem;
    border: 2px solid #0c5a9d;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 604px;
    display: block;
    margin: 35px auto;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #0c5a9d;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.btn_ol:hover {
    background: #0c5a9d;
    border-color: #0c5a9d;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn_ol a{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.btn_ol span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    will-change: transform;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btn_ol:hover span {
    transform: translate3d(-1rem, 0, 0);
}

.btn_ol .ol_svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto 5px;
    top: 25%;
    width: 1.1em;
    right: -0.5rem;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    will-change: right;
}

.btn_ol .ol_svg * {
    stroke-width: 5;
}

.btn_ol:hover .ol_svg {
    opacity: 1;
    right: -3.5rem;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .btn_ol { 
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2.3rem 1.1rem;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }
    .btn_ol span {
        line-height: 1.8rem;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    .btn_ol .ol_svg {
        top: 15%;
        right: 0rem;
    }

    .btn_ol:hover .ol_svg {
        right: -2.5rem;
    }
}
```

In this CSS, we are trying to achieve the following
- Text and svg files move when hovering
- Color is reversed when hovering.
- Open the link

There was no problem with the PC, but I found a problem with the SP site operation.

When operating on a tablet, it takes two clicks to jump the link. The first click keeps the hover on and the second click opens the window.

Apparently I was able to confirm that removing

```
.btn_ol:hover .ol_svg {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

would open the link on the first tap, but I'm not sure how to implement it while keeping the SVG view.

please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

```html
<div class="btn_ol">
    <a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">
        <span>
             Google<img src="../assets/images/common/icon_ol.svg" type="image/svg+xml"> 
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Working for me.

Comment: you can use tag <img src="image.svg"> .      Tag <img src="image.svg"> working with all format

Answer (score 0):

It is common to use images as links.  Don't forget to enclose them in your  tag.

```
<div class="btn_ol">
    <a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">
        <span>Google<object class=ol_svg data="../assets/images/common/icon_ol.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Mr. DANIEL.
Thank you for your answer.
I tried it, but I got the same thing when I enclosed span with a tag.